# Filter double data value to 1 only

Tags: php

I want to filter same value on field to only one. the code look like this.

I have 4 fields: **id**, **alphabet**, **user**, **message** with data:

```
id   alphabet    user    message 
-------------------------------------
 1   A           Ant     how are you?
 2   A           Ant     I'm fine.
 3   A           Atelier hehe.
 4   A           Atelier hoho.
```

**Query**

```
$a = "SELECT user FROM database WHERE alphabet = 'A'";

$b = mysql_query($a);

$c=mysql_num_rows($b);

for ($d=0; $d < $c; ++$d)
{
    $e[]=mysql_fetch_array($b);
    echo $e[$d][0].'<br>';
}
```

With above code it dump all user value that match **A** how make it **2** data with same it just show **1** like this. **ant** **atelier** only instead ***ant ant atelier atelier***?

Comment: it's wrong typo i have edited it. thank you. hehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update you query using the word `DISTINCT`

`Disticnt`  helps in removing duplicates from the output.

```
$a = "SELECT DISTINCT user FROM database WHERE alphabet = 'A'";
```

This will select rows 1 and 3 only, assuming id is primary key and no ordering option.

Comment: IIRC it could be rows 2+3, 1+4 and 2+4 as well; I don't think the spec says anything particular about the order.

Comment: "assuming id is primary key" - I don't think that actually matters here; it will have similar results without any primary key.

Comment: @zkanoca thank you. but is there anyway filter with array instead query?